# Calculate the uncertainty in components of composite model in Lmfit

Tags: python, model, components, composite, lmfit

I have a model defined as
gmodel=Model(a)+Model(b)
result=gmodel.fit(data,...)
I use this model to fit the data, which gives me the parameters and their error estimates. Using the result.eval_components(), I could access the component a and component b of the model function. Also, using result.eval_uncertainty(), I could access the 1-sigma uncertainties in the model functions, which would be two lines. Now I want to know each component a and b in that 1-sigma uncertainty lines.Is there a easy way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

There is not currently "an easy way of doing this" - the `eval_uncertainty` method belongs to the `lmfit.ModelResult`, not the `lmfit.Model` itself, at least partly because it needs the resulting covariance matrix.

But: I think `eval_uncertainty` method could probably calculate the uncertainty in any component models too.  I would suggest raising an Issue and/or using the lmfit mailing list to discuss making this change.